# Error during migration while setting up Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, migration

I'm relatively new to Rails and I'm running into an issue while trying to set up Devise. I believe the issue stems from the fact that I already generated a user scaffold before trying to install Devise, yet I don't know how to solve this problem. When I proceed through the Devise setup, I get to the step where I have to enter the following code:

```
rails generate devise User
```

That works, and I get this back from terminal:

```
invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20120609032448_add_devise_to_users.rb
  insert    app/models/user.rb
   route  devise_for :users
```

The next step is to migrate the database, which I attempt but get the following error:

```
==  AddDeviseToUsers: migrating ===============================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email"         varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I've tried destroying the original User scaffold along with the original User migration but I keep getting stuck at this error. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Your new migration probably has an `email` column defined in it. Comment that line regarding adding an `email` column out and run it again. It's likely you've already got an email column in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to this file

```
db/migrate/20120609032448_add_devise_to_users.rb
```

and in the code where it says

```
change_table(:users)...
```

alter this to

```
create_table(:users)...
```

Comment: When you make that change a new error:SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" varchar, "reset_password_sent_at" datetime, "remember_created_at" datetime, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, "current_sign_in_at" datetime, "last_sign_in_at" datetime, "current_sign_in_ip" varchar, "last_sign_in_ip" varchar) /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'